# java was started but returned exit code= -8053306369

Tags: eclipse, drupal, eclipse-pdt

I get a java tm platform se binary is not responding error in eclipse when i try to open the file modules/system/html.tpl.php from my acquia-drupal installation. ( i can open other tpl.php like modules/system/page.tpl.php in eclipse ).
When i close eclipse i get this error:

java was started but returned exit code= -8053306369

I'm not allowed to post images, but you can see the full error here: http://premiserunningthin.de/eclipse_805306369_error.jpg

I can open the file modules/system/html.tpl.php in my other editors e.g. komodo or notepad++. But i prefer to do all my work in eclipse because its my favorite editor.
Does anyone have any clues for this problem?
Thanks

Comment: That might be Eclipse PDT issue. Try Aptana PHP editor as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to use another editor.

Comment: It's an editor within Eclipse.

Comment: Ok. I have installed the Aptana plugin for eclipse (http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install). But i don't know how to run the editor or make it the default editor in eclipse?

Comment: Use "Open With >" context menu on a file. For making default go to Preferences/General/Editors/File Associations

Comment: when I open the file modules/system/html.tpl.php using the aptana php editor eclipse dosn't crash. And i can choose the eclipse color theme: preferences -> Aptana -> Themes. I will give the aptana editor a go. Thanks for the help Max.

Answer (score 1):

http://spacetech.dk/eclipse-failed-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369.html

The error was due to a corrupt workspace. As I disable the workspace check in the startup I couldn’t select another workspace since Eclipse wouldn’t start. Rename the workspace e.g. to “workspace1″. Eclipse will start and create a new uncorrupted workspace and work without any problems. Afterwards you can import your project into your new workspace and in the end remove the old corrupted workspace.

Answer (score -2):

That might be Eclipse PDT issue. Try Aptana PHP editor instead.